# When to use TaskFactory in Asp.Net Web applications (webform or mvc)?

Tags: asp.net, async-await, task

I am working in WPF now...here we use Background_Worker,TaskFactory.StartNew functions and async/await.

In web apps I know that we have AJAX, MVC partial views etc.

My question is do we really use above mentioned async methods (Tasks, sync/await) in Web apps ? If we use, could you give me some examples ?

I have a document generation module in my web app in which I have to fetch data from DB and create documents out of it. Is it a good scenario for async calls? (to call the function and throw..and never care about it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am working in WPF now...here we use Background_Worker,TaskFactory.StartNew functions and async/await.

You really should be using `Task.Run` instead of `BackgroundWorker` and `Task.Factory.StartNew`. `Task.Run` has much better defaults than `StartNew`, and is more composable and type-safe than `BackgroundWorker`.

> My question is do we really use above mentioned async methods (Tasks, sync/await) in Web apps ?

On ASP.NET, you should almost never use your own background threads (`BackgroundWorker`, `StartNew`, `Task.Run`). However, you certainly can use `async` and `await`.

> If we use, could you give me some examples ? I have a document generation module in my web app in which I have to fetch data from DB and create documents out of it.

Yes, [database queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj819165.aspx) are one example of an I/O-based operation. So is "writing" documents - whether as uploads to cloud storage or to the local file system.

I have an [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx) on `async` ASP.NET that you may find useful.

Answer (score 1):

Async is useful any time you have disk/database/network I/O. It allows you to do other things while you wait for the I/O to complete, which can result in significant savings. Async isn't really useful for normal CPU bound operations, because of the increased overhead of making it async.

This holds true in WPF as well web applications.

If you want to see a concrete example, Scott Hanselman has a blog entry entitled [The Magic of using Asynchronous Methods in ASP.NET 4.5 plus an important gotcha](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheMagicOfUsingAsynchronousMethodsInASPNET45PlusAnImportantGotcha.aspx) which you may find very interesting.